# How can I make responsiveness test on flutter

Tags: flutter, testing, android-emulator, emulation, responsiveness

I'm developing flutter on windows 10, could you recommend some plugins or emulators that I can test my app in different sizes ?

Comment: Compile to desktop and resize the window

Comment: genius answer man thanks.

Comment: unfortunately some libraries are not compatible with flutter web or desktop in my project.  So I need really a good emulator that I can test on different layout options.

Comment: IDK of an emulator you could resize, maybe you could the same emulator bundled with android studio, select a large tablet and use https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview to test different and lower device screen sizes. Might not be the best allternative but is doable

Comment: Thanks that this package will be helpful !

Answer (score 0):

At least you can use VirtualBox and set different screen sizes

*UPDATE*:
I misunderstood the question. You can use IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio as coding software AND emulator. There's a feature that makes it possible to run your app instantly on an emulator. [Check this out.](https://simonotoole.medium.com/getting-started-with-flutter-for-intellij-d4f45f2067b0) You can set different devices and different screen sizes. Even custom device.

Comment: I have downloaded virtualbox for gennymotion I guess. I couldn't make google apps work with gennymotion so I gave up on it. How can I use VirtualBox as you suggested ?

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry. I've misunderstood you. I thought you want to run windows apps in different sizes. You can use IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio as coding software AND emulator. There's a feature that makes it possible to run your app instantly on an emulator. [Check this out.](https://simonotoole.medium.com/getting-started-with-flutter-for-intellij-d4f45f2067b0) You can set different devices and different screen sizes. Even custom device.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) I wish emulators of android studio were not 86x.